# Activate Dropdown Toggle on Default button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to activate dropdown toggle button on the click of default button but by doing debigging i get to know that dropdown comes but it then disappears.

I am unable to recollect why is it happening?

I have put my code on http://jsfiddle.net/9r14uuLw/31/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <!-- Button Group -->
          <label><h5>Status</h5></label>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group" >   
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id = 'StatusBtn' onclick="clicktogglebutton()" >Select One</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id = 'togglebtn1' data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="caret"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Status 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Status 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Status 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Please do loo at it and let me know , what may be the possible tweak i need in the code to make it work.

Comment: Do you want to implement like select options ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be preferable to use a standard `<select>` element for this role, as it's better both functionally and semantically.

However, if you're set on rolling your own, why have two buttons? Try condensing it to a single element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Select One
  <span class="caret"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
```